# Defining a smart pointer as a member variable of a class

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, smart-pointers

Header:

```
CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView m_pHtmlView  = nullptr;
```

Source:

```
m_pHtmlView = new CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView();
```

---

Trying to change it to use a smart pointer. I can do this (inside `OnInitDialog`):

```
auto m_pHtmlView2 = std::make_unique<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView>;
```

But I can't work out how to have my smart pointer defined as a member variable of my `CDialog` class. I can't do: `std::unique_ptr m_pHtmlView2`.

---

I saw this discussion ([Using smart pointers as a class member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473733/using-smart-pointers-as-a-class-member)) and based on that I tried this in the header:

```
//CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView *m_pHtmlView;
std::unique_ptr<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView> m_pHtmlView;
```

But that will not compile:

```
6>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30704\include\memory(3087,1): error C2248: 'CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView::~CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView': cannot access protected member declared in class 'CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView'
6>D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\ChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView.h(104): message : compiler has generated 'CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView::~CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView' here
6>D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\ChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView.h(22): message : see declaration of 'CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView'
6>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30704\include\memory(3085): message : while compiling class template member function 'void std::default_delete<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView>::operator ()(_Ty *) noexcept const'
6>        with
6>        [
6>            _Ty=CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView
6>        ]
6>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30704\include\memory(3195): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::default_delete<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView>::operator ()(_Ty *) noexcept const' being compiled
6>        with
6>        [
6>            _Ty=CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView
6>        ]
6>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30704\include\memory(3122): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::default_delete<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView>' being compiled
6>D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\AvailableBrothersReportPreview.h(52): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::unique_ptr<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView,std::default_delete<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView>>' being compiled
```

---

#### Update

Based on the advice in the comments I now have:

- Header:

`std::unique_ptr<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView> m_pHtmlView;`

- Source (in `OnInitDialog`):

```
m_pHtmlView = std::make_unique<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView>();
if (m_pHtmlView != nullptr)
{
    m_pHtmlView->Create(nullptr, nullptr, AFX_WS_DEFAULT_VIEW,
                            m_rctPreviewHtml, this, 0);
    m_pHtmlView->ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    if(CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::WaitForFileToBeReady(m_strTempHtmlFile))
        m_pHtmlView->Navigate2(m_strTempHtmlFile, 0, nullptr);
}
```

It complies and works. My popup dialog displays and the `CHtmlView` derived control is visible. Cool. But when I click OK to close the dialog I get an exception:

[image]

How do we address that?

Comment: `unique_ptr` needs access to `CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView`'s destructor. The error message seems to suggest that the (compiler-generated) destructor is protected. Either make the destructor public, or make `unique_ptr<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView>` a `friend`. The latter is fairly tricky, and should only be considered as a last resort.

Comment: @IInspectable I changed the destructor to public. It then compiled but the `m_pHtmlView` was saying it was empty. In OID I then tried: `m_pHtmlView = std::unique_ptr<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView>();` and it is STILL empty. So whilst it all compiles, I get no view.

Comment: A default-constructed `unique_ptr` holds a null pointer. `unique_ptr<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView>()` invokes the default constructor as well, so that expression also evaluates to a `unique_ptr` that holds a null pointer. `make_unique` is what constructs the object, returning a `unique_ptr` that holds the address of that object. Note that the code in the question (`auto m_pHtmlView2 = std::make_unique<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView>;`) creates a new variable, and assigns it a function pointer (I believe). The expression is missing `()`, thus evaluating to a function.

Comment: @IInspectable I know my example was making a local pointer. But that was the reason for my question. I could only make it work with a local pointer and not with a class member variable. If I don't use the brackets in the header and don't use them in OID it tells me that the type name is not allowed.

Comment: `unique_ptr` is usually useful within a block scope, and usually for primitive data types. In this case, it looks like you are using `new` in a different way. Does the compiler complain?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani No - it worked fine, Just code analysis stuff.

Comment: I meant to ask if code analysis is complaining.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Yes, telling me to use these `make_unique` pointers etc... and not `new` ...

Comment: In the class definition: `std::unique_ptr<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView> m_pHtmlView;`. In constructor: `m_pHtmlView = std::make_unique<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView>();` (note a pair of parentheses at the end; `std::make_unique<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView>` is a function that needs to be actually called).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I think also that in my code I had a if(xxx != nullptr). And then it creates the internal element - the control. This smart pointer itself can’t be tested against that. If I comment that test out I think it will be ok. I will try, along with your tweaks.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik See updated question. 1 step forward and 2 steps back.

Comment: @bar `unique_ptr` is useful in all cases where one needs to model exclusive ownership of pointed-to data with value semantics. A class member is as valid a use-case as a local variable with automatic storage duration. The concrete type isn't very interesting. It is the feature of tying reachability and lifetime back together, that matters. A feature that's missing from raw pointers.

Comment: This looks like a double-delete bug. Are you trying to manually delete the pointee held in the `unique_ptr` at some point, e.g. from the destructor?

Comment: @IInspectable No. I did have code in `OnDestroy` where I still do `m_pHtmlView->DestroyWindow();` but I commented out the code to delete the pointer.

Comment: @IInspectable My class derives from `CHtmlView`.

Comment: Somewhere in the code not shown, you have double destruction. Possibly not of `m_pHtmlView` directly, but of the class it's a member of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CHtmlView` is derived from `CFormView` -> `CView`, which deletes itself  in `CView::PostNcDestroy` with `delete this;` So the memory is already managed.

Replace `new` with `std::make_unique`, and call `release()` immediately, because you don't want `unique_ptr` to delete it anymore.

```
//m_pHtmlView = new CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView();
m_pHtmlView = std::make_unique<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView>().release();
```

If you had written `new` and `delete` in your original code (that also means you at least override `CMyHtmlView::PostNcDestroy`) then `unique_ptr` can be used to replace both `new` and `delete`.

In this case, you only had `new` in the original code. You don't want `unique_ptr` to manage `delete`

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the declaration of the variable in OID as instructed. But I do not have a `PostNcDestroy` in my class so that is the default `CHtmlView` version I guess. The place where I was called `delete` was in my dialogs `OnDestroy`. Actually, my original `OnDestroy` seems to just call `DestroyWindow()` and then sets the pointer to `null`. No actual `delete` call.

Comment: So it looks like I just create it, as you instructed, and do not delete it because it will be deleted by `CView::PostNcDestroy` I guess. I don;t have a memory leak. And according to source control I have never called `delete m_pHtmlView`.

Comment: Okay good. You should create a separate project and write a small "hello world" console program, to test out `unique_ptr` and other C++ feature. It's difficult learn this in a large MFC project with `CHtmlView` and other classes which are already complicated.